# Pant legs or pants legs?

Tags: word-usage

With all this I don't see the answer to which is the correct form "He rolled up his pant legs" or "he rolled up his pants legs."

Comment: Both are common, and it doesn't matter which one you use.

Answer (score 3):

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) gives 130 hits for "pant legs" and 58 hits for "pants legs". So both are used by native speakers, and one is not hugely more common than the other. You can use whichever one you think sounds better.

Answer (score 0):

Ngram Viewer, imperfect as it is, [suggests that "pant legs"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pant+legs%2Cpants+legs&year_start=2000&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) is the more common construction, though both versions are reasonably common.

**There is a reason for the confusion here.** Noun adjuncts in this situation are typically singular: we talk about "his shirt sleeves," not "his *shirts sleeves," assuming he has only one shirt.

This creates something of a problem when we try to use "pants" as a noun adjunct modifying "legs." This is because "pants" is a bipartite noun existing only in the plural; since there is no singular, we can't make an adjunct the usual way.

So we have two choices. First, we can break the usual rule and keep "pants" as plural, giving us "pants legs." Alternatively, we can invent a singular word "pant" and use *that* as the adjunct, giving us "pant legs."

In the end, "pant legs" and "pants legs" each break one of the rules. It's just a question of which rule you choose to break. If you prefer an awkward plural noun adjunct, go with "pants legs." If you're OK with inventing a singular "pant," you can go with "pant legs." Per Ngram Viewer, it seems that most people go with the latter option.

Comment: "Trousers" is also a bipartite noun and is far more common in British English where "pants" more usually refers to underpants (or "shorts" in US English) . In BrEn virtually no one ever says "trousers legs" we say "trouser legs" for the plural (eg "his trouser legs were soaked") , "trouser leg" for the singular (eg "his right trouser leg was torn by his bicycle chain") or variations  on "the legs of <posessive> trousers" (eg "the legs of his trousers were soaked" and "the right leg of his trousers was torn). For that reason I'd go with "pant legs" myself.

Answer (score -1):

It's a pair of pants not a pair of pant. A pair of pants, as in trousers (not trouser). A pant is something a dog does because it cannot sweat.